# I don't understand how i can to parse file .ts

Tags: mpeg, mpeg2-ts

Good afternoon.  I am a beginner programmer. I am doing a training project in which I am trying to combine video and audio into one .ts container. What information comes after the staffing bytes on this screenshot.

[TS-analyser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmwFw.jpg)

Comment: Can you please state the question more clearly.

Comment: ok, how do you think that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That packet is PID 0, which make the payload a Program Association Table (PAT).

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream#PAT

Comment: ok,if it's PAT  I have an error section_syntax_indicator == 0b0, and reserved bit == 0b01

Comment: No. 0xb0 = 0b1011  hence. section_syntax_indicator= 1, private bit =0  and reserved bits = 11

Comment: That's right, thank you. But it's not clear why we flip the first byte after FF, 0b00 is the number table_id and what does the second 0b00 mean before 0xB0 ?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by flips the first byte. But I believe you are forgetting to count the pointer field.

Comment: Please advise 166 bytes to be counted from the first stacking byte (0xFF), immediately after 0xA600

Comment: 0xA6 is the fifth byte. 166 + 5 = 171, which is the first byte after the stuffing. I don't know why you are not counting the flags. Please read the wikipedia articles on transport streams. It's all documented there. If you have more questions. Please make a new post.